# VM cannot share vpn connection of the host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager, vpn

I'm currently using MacOS as a host and Ubuntu as guests, and the guest can use network connection of the host. However although I set the network settings as NAT and paravirtualized network, it just cannot use the VPN of the host.

I tried `VBoxManage modifyvm "myVM" --natdnsproxy1 on` as well but it makes no sense and the guest still cannot use that VPN connection. Does any one know the reason of this or how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: ubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64

Comment: On the host Mac, have you toggled the option to send *all* network traffic through the VPN? So long as the VM is getting its network information from the Mac and not the network DHCP server, traffic should be routed properly.

Comment: I'm currently using clashX as my vpn client app, and somehow there's no vpn related settings in Mac's own settings. I also checked the clashX settings but there's no similar things